# MVC - Model View inside of another Model View

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, automapper

Is it good practice to use one model view inside of another one and how will AutoMapper work with it?

Example:

```
public class CustomerModelView
{
 public string FullName {get;set;}
 public string IList<OrderListModelView>(get;set;)
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking: How does AutoMapper maps lists in Model View.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we do this quite often.  In fact, in many cases we'll re-use ViewModels for partials, so in this case, you could have a partial for IList (or just a single one), so that multiple screens that display the common snippet re-use both the ViewModel and the partial view.

To do this in AutoMapper, you'll need to create a map for Customer -> CustomerModelView and Order -> OrderListModelView.  There is nothing special you need to do for lists of items, you only need to map the element types.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that this is better way than using model object inside of another model view.